# Create Search box with highlighting found data - Blazor -

Tags: c#, html, search, blazor

I am working on creating blazor page that display search box to search from list , i want the matching string not the whole word to be highlighted if it match the input in search box the result now is
`<mark>ap</mark>`
and here is the code :

```
@page "/test"
@using System.Linq

<input type="text" @bind-value="@searchTerm" @bind-value:event="oninput" placeholder="Search" />

<ul>
    @foreach (var item in filteredItems)
    {
        <li>@GetHighlightedText(item)</li>
    }
</ul>

@code {
    private string searchTerm = "";

    private List<string> items = new List<string> { "apple", "banana", "cherry", "date", "elderberry" };

    private List<string> filteredItems
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm))
            {
                return items;
            }
            else
            {
                return items.Where(item => item.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
            }
        }
    }

    private string GetHighlightedText(string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm))
        {
            return text;
        }

        int index = text.IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (index < 0)
        {
            return text;
        }

        string before = text.Substring(0, index);
        string match = text.Substring(index, searchTerm.Length);
        string after = text.Substring(index + searchTerm.Length);

        return $"{before}<mark>{match}</mark>{after}";
    }
}
<style>
    mark {
        background-color: yellow;
        color: black;
    }
</style>
```

I try to change the browser or change `mark` tag but i still have the same problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you actually want to do and how is it failing?

Comment: @LajosArpad sure . I want to be able to search in this list , for example : if i search for A i want the letter A from words contains this letter to be highlighted or colored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing :

```
<li>@GetHighlightedText(item)</li>
```

to :

```
<li> @((MarkupString)GetHighlightedText(item)) </li>
```

Comment: Thanks !!!
it's perfectly working .